# Theming translation links

Tags: theming, navigation, i18n-l10n

I need to change translation links attributes, which have been defined in [translation_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!translation!translation.module/function/translation_node_view/7) function in these lines:

```
$node->content['links']['translation'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'links__node__translation',
  '#links' => $links,
  '#attributes' => array('class' => array('links', 'inline')),
);
```

I'd like to override these attributes in my custom module.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. May be useful for others I think:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_node_view_alter(&$build) {
    if (isset($build['links']['translation'])){
        $build['links'] = array(
            'translation' => array(
                '#theme' => 'links__node__translation',
                '#links' => $build['links']['translation']['#links'],
                '#attributes' => array('id' => 'translation_links')
            )
        );
    }
}
```

** Now my links have their own ID, so I can customize them as I need with css

* If you need to custom only these links, I suggest to use MYTHEME_node_view_alter()*